# Oracle LAG/LEAD analytic functions works as join or not?

Tags: oracle

**lag**/**lead** analytic functions allow access to previous/next rows without join technique according official docs:

- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions074.htm

Does that mean that if I include fields which are not *lag/lead* - Oracle do join on this fields?

So if I query currency rates (to find holes - the day where are no rate defined):

```
 select CURRENCY, RATE, XDATE, lead(XDATE) over (order by XDATE) from CURRENCY_RATE
```

I get *lead(XDATE)* for same *CURRENCY* as *XDATE*?

Or **partition by** keyword in **lead** expression must be used on  *CURRENCY* to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query make a lead without currency consideration.
If you want to sort by date for any currency, you need to add the partition by keyword :

```
select CURRENCY,
       RATE,
       XDATE,
       lead(XDATE) over(partition by CURRENCY order by XDATE)
  from CURRENCY_RATE
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found good explanation of analytical functions semantic in http://www.orafaq.com/node/55 :

- Some functions support the *window_clause* inside the partition to further limit the records they act on. In the absence of any *window_clause* analytic functions are computed on all the records of the partition clause.
- The functions SUM, COUNT, AVG, MIN, MAX are the common analytic functions the result of which does not depend on the order of the records.
- Functions like LEAD, LAG, RANK, DENSE_RANK, ROW_NUMBER, FIRST, FIRST VALUE, LAST, LAST VALUE depends on order of records.

Another nice docs: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions.php